# php Arrays within arrays and calling certain values inside those arrays

Tags: php, arrays

Hello i have a really odd question, i have a couple of arrays that are within arrays they are inside a DB,and they are "product attributes" so basically a product can have unlimited amount of attributes.

**My question is this:**

So when i go and print them out like this

```
<?php print_r($attr['values'][0]) ?>
```

i get this

```
Array ( [attribute_value_id] => 13 [name] => Country )
```

and this

```
Array ( [attribute_value_id] => 15 [name] => Town )
```

How can i call those 2 arrays seperatly as **[attribute_value_id] => 13** and **[attribute_value_id] => 15** i want to call them as 13 and 15 values seperatly?

Is this even possible?

**Update:**

```
<?php if ($attr['attribute_type'] == MsAttribute::TYPE_SELECT) { ?>
        <select id="firstSelect" name="product_attributes[<?php echo $attr['attribute_id']; ?>]">
        <option value="0"><?php echo $text_select; ?></option>
        <option value="<?php echo $attr['values'][0]['attribute_value_id'] ?>" <?php if (isset($normal_attribute_values[$attr['attribute_id']]) && array_key_exists($attr['values'][0]['attribute_value_id'], $normal_attribute_values[$attr['attribute_id']])) { ?>selected="selected"<?php } ?>><?php echo $attr['values'][0]['name']; ?></option>
        </select>
    <?php } ?>
```

This is the code inside my template file

Comment: What is the **exact** output of: `print_r($attr['values'][0])` ?

Comment: @Rizier123 that is the exact output of it, both of those lines

Comment: That can't be the real output, either your code is in a loop or These 2 arrays are inside another array, (`Array(...)`)

Comment: its pulling them from a DB,they are all stored in the same table,both of those lines are 2 different "attributes" 
1-st attribute group is for Countrys and the second one is for Towns

Comment: Just show us your **real** code.

Answer (score 0):

use simple `foreach()` function as shown in the below example

```
foreach($attr['values'][0] as $value)
{
     echo $value['attribute_value_id']."<br/>" ;
     echo $value['name'];
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this is going to help me? when i need 1 of those 2 not every 1 of them i just need the 1-st one only without getting the 2-nd one

Comment: @Innervisions Just access the first array: `print_r($attr['values'][0][0]);` ?!

Comment: @Innervisions, that is even more simple as explained by Rizier

Comment: @Rizier123 i tried that thing long time ago!! i get an  Notice: Undefined offset: 0 ,there is no 2-nd ['0'] in there i can only access ['attribute_value_id'] or ['name']  and when i call them like that i get both of them!!

Comment: @Innervisions Show us your **real** and **full** output from: `print_r($attr['values'][0]);` and copy the **entire** output here.

Comment: @Rizier123
I get this!
Array ( [attribute_value_id] => 13 [name] => Country [image] => http://mystupidsite/shop/image/tmp/no_image-50x50.jpg [sort_order] => 0 ) 
and this!
Array ( [attribute_value_id] => 15 [name] => Town [image] => http://mystupidsite/shop/image/tmp/no_image-50x50.jpg [sort_order] => 1 )

I still dont know how this will help you

Comment: @Innervisions Then your code is inside of a loop. Show us this code.

Comment: access it as :
`$attr['values'][0]['attribute_value_id'];$attr['values'][0]['name'];` etc.

Comment: @Rizier123 i posted the code on the top 10 minutes ago and ofcourse that it is inside a loop,every product can have multiple attributes they are all stored in the same place thats just the code that makes it visible

Comment: @Innervisions Then what is the problem/question ?

Comment: @Rizier123 How to call [attribute_value_id] => 13 without [attribute_value_id] => 15

i need to call the attribute value id as 15 or as 13 i just want to call that stupid country

Comment: i have showen you in above comment of mine, just replace index 0 with other numbers, i suggest you read some array tutorials

Comment: @Innervisions Then why you don't just do what Sourabh said above: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33249268/php-arrays-within-arrays-and-calling-certain-values-inside-those-arrays/33249318?noredirect=1#comment54300893_33249318 ?

Comment: because i get Illegal string offset 'attribute_value_id'  and for "name" aswell

Comment: @Innervisions Your question is unclear and there is something which you don't show us here. And I don't play the guess game.

Comment: @Rizier123 I am showing you everything...everything you and  Sourabh said i tried it,even if it kicked out an error,i still got both of the values,they both are from a DB they are all looped because it has to be for each product inside the store,but what ever...it's pointless i will just go another route..gonna close the post,thanks for the help anyways

Comment: When you want to access a single value then do not go inside a foreach it is that simple.

Answer (score 0):

If your output is accurate, what you have is this:

```
Array( 'values' => Array(
    0 => Array ( [attribute_value_id] => 13 [name] => Country ),
    1 => Array ( [attribute_value_id] => 15 [name] => Town )
    )
)
```

Knowing this, you could do the following:

```
echo $attr['values'][0]['attribute_value_id']; // will echo 13
echo $attr['values'][0]['name']; // will echo Country
echo $attr['values'][1]['attribute_value_id']; // will echo 15
echo $attr['values'][1]['name']; // will echo Town
```

But, if you only know that you want the attribute ID of the Town name, then you must do this:

```
    foreach($attr['values'] as $data)
    {
        if($data['name'] == 'Town')
        {
            echo $data['attribute_value_d'];
        }
        // If not, do nothing.
    }
```

If you have control over the array, consider using associative arrays through out rather then enumerated:

```
Array( 'values' => Array(
    'Country' => Array ( [attribute_value_id] => 13 [name] => Country ),
    'Town' => Array ( [attribute_value_id] => 15 [name] => Town )
    )
)
```

So then you can:

```
echo $attr['values']['Country']['attribute_value_id']; // will echo 13
echo $attr['values']['Country']['name']; // will echo Country
echo $attr['values']['Town']['attribute_value_id']; // will echo 15
echo $attr['values']['Town']['name']; // will echo Town
```

Enumerated vs Associated arrays really depend on your business logic as to which works best for you.